# Polymorphic type discriminator is not converted to enum during deserialization

Tags: c#, enums, system.text.json, polymorphic-deserialization

I'm using enum field as type discriminator for polymorphic serialization/deserialization and faced strange behavior. A string value that is a type discriminator is not converted to enum and sets the default value of this enum.

Here's my **C# model**

```cs
[JsonPolymorphic(TypeDiscriminatorPropertyName = "type")]
[JsonDerivedType(typeof(FixedPenalty), typeDiscriminator: "fixedPenalty")]
[JsonDerivedType(typeof(FixedRatePenalty), typeDiscriminator: "fixedRatePenalty")]
[JsonDerivedType(typeof(RelativePenalty), typeDiscriminator: "relativePenalty")]
public abstract class Penalty
{
    public PenaltyType Type { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public Penalty(PenaltyType type,
        string description)
    {
        Type = type;
        Description = description;
    }
}
```

Here's **json** that I send to the controller.

```js
{
   "type": "relativePenalty",
   "description": "string",
   "rate": 10.9,
   "unit": "year"
}
```

As you can see the deserialization is working correctly, the object is of the correct type, however the enum is not being converted.

[image: Debug]

Is there any way to fix this behavior? Now I see two ways to solve the problem, either add a technical field purely for the discriminator to **DTO model**, which will duplicate "type" field, or check for the type casting and then convert to the desired model from a specific application layer, but I don't like these two ways.

Comment: Why do you need a `Type` property? It seems to be certain for child classes.

Comment: @shingo I need this in other parts of the system.

Comment: Oh, yeah. Got you. Penalty was previously not abstract and has its own PenaltyType.